# How to access the source paths for loaded map tiles

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I've a local map server that renders a mbtiles file in the browser and I'm trying to access the source files generated by it and loaded on the document.

So far I've been able to get my hands on the respective HTMLcollection with the `document.querySelector` and `document.getElementsByClassName()` methods:

```
var collection = 
  document.querySelector(".featured")
  .getElementsByClassName("leaflet-tile");

console.log(collection);
```

I get the following log on Firebug:

```
0 img.leaflet-tile.leaflet-tile-loaded ./tiles/b...1540.png
1 img.leaflet-tile.leaflet-tile-loaded ./tiles/b...1540.png
2 img.leaflet-tile.leaflet-tile-loaded ./tiles/b...1541.png
3 img.leaflet-tile.leaflet-tile-loaded ./tiles/b...1541.png
4 img.leaflet-tile.leaflet-tile-loaded ./tiles/b...1540.png
5 img.leaflet-tile.leaflet-tile-loaded ./tiles/b...1540.png
6 img.leaflet-tile.leaflet-tile-loaded ./tiles/b...1541.png
7 img.leaflet-tile.leaflet-tile-loaded ./tiles/b...1541.png
8 img.leaflet-tile.leaflet-tile-loaded ./tiles/b...1540.png
9 img.leaflet-tile.leaflet-tile-loaded ./tiles/b...1540.png
10 img.leaflet-tile.leaflet-tile-loaded ./tiles/b...1541.png
11 img.leaflet-tile.leaflet-tile-loaded ./tiles/b...1541.png
12 img.leaflet-tile.leaflet-tile-loaded ./tiles/b...1540.png
13 img.leaflet-tile.leaflet-tile-loaded ./tiles/b...1541.png
length 14
__proto__ HTMLCollection { item=item(),  namedItem=namedItem()}
```

I tried everything I could remember to get hold of the paths for the png files. For instance:

```
var array = [];

for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
    array.push([
        collection[i]
]);
    console.log(collection[i]);
}

console.log("lenght of collection is: " + collection.length);
console.dir("array is: " + array);
```

On my console I get the following:

```
lenght of collection is: 0
array is: undefined
```

A lenght of zero and nothing on my array. It's obvious that I'm doing something wrong on my iteration, but I cannot figure it out. What I'm missing here? Thank you in advance!

---

Server-side I'm using [PHP Tileserver](https://github.com/infostreams/mbtiles-php). This is how I instantiate the map object:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    window.map = new L.map('map', {
        zoomControl: false,
    })
        .setView([40.6420, -73.7854], 12);

    var mapTiles = './tiles/bojb/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';

    L.tileLayer(
        mapTiles, {
            maxZoom: 16,
            minZoom: 12
        }).addTo(map);
```

Comment: I see this question is also at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/180976/how-to-access-png-tiles-loaded-in-the-browser

Comment: In future, please do not cross-post questions on multiple Stack Exchange sites; instead, post your question on one, and wait for an answer. If you later discover your question was asked on the *wrong* site, flag it and ask a moderator to migrate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `tileload` and `tileunload` events fired by `L.TileLayer`:

Tileload:

> Fired when a tile loads.

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer-tileload

Tileunload:

> Fired when a tile is removed (e.g. when you have unloadInvisibleTiles on).

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer-tileunload

```
var tilelayer = new L.TileLayer('//{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    'attribution': '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, &copy; <a href="http://cartodb.com/attributions">CartoDB</a>'
});

var tilesloaded = [];

tilelayer.on('tileload', function (e) {
    if (tilesloaded.indexOf(e.url) === -1) {
        tilesloaded.push(e.url);
    }
});

tilelayer.on('tileunload', function (e) {
    var index = tilesloaded.indexOf(e.tile.src);
    tilesloaded.splice(index, 1);
});
```

Now the `tilesloaded` array will always contain an accurate representation of the tiles that are currently loaded by the tilelayer.

Here's a working example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/mKOFDzEmVp9111Pr0tfb?p=preview

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't familiar with the `tileload` and `tileunload` events. Unfortunately, I tried your code, but still no luck. I wonder if this is due to how I instantiate the map object? Server-side, I'm using [PHP TileServer](https://github.com/infostreams/mbtiles-php). Btw, just updated the code above with a snippet of how I instantiante the map object on my application. A trained eye may easily spot something that a noob like myself won't! ;-) Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Well, I got it working! I now have an array of strings with full source paths of the images. The problem was unrelated with the question itself (it had to do with the scope of the variable for the L.tileLayer instance).

Comment: Good to hear! Added an example to my answer for future users.